# App stucks when using Qt and pynput at same time in Python

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, pynput

I am now developing an app that need to detect whenever the user selects some text on any place on their computer and do ctrl-c, then get the text from the clipboard. For the user interface, I am now also using PyQt.

But now I find that if I am using the two at the same time in my program, it will stuck at the beginning. I am new to programming but I guess that it may be due to the problem of threading.

Here is the code extracted from my program that can show the problem:

app.py:

```
from copy_view import Copy_view
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyboardListener
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.mouse import Button
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    global copy_view
    copy_view = Copy_view()

    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed and button == Button.left:
            copy_view.drag.click(x, y)
        else:
            result = copy_view.drag.release(x, y)
            if result:
                text = copy_view.get_text()
                copy_view.add_text(text)

    listener = MouseListener(on_click=on_click)
    listener.start()

    def on_press(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            listener.stop()
    exitListener = KeyboardListener(on_release=on_press)
    exitListener.start()

    listener.join()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

copy_view.py:

````
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget,
    QListView,
    QVBoxLayout,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QStandardItemModel,
    QStandardItem,
)
import win32clipboard as wClip
from drag import Drag, do_copy

class Copy_view(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drag = Drag()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.texts = []
        self.texts_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.texts_view = QListView(self)

        # layout
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 300, 500)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.texts_view)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.show()

    def initUI_setup(self):
        self.texts_view.setModel(self.texts_model)
        self.texts_view.setWordWrap(True)

    def get_text(self):
        do_copy()
        wClip.OpenClipboard()
        text = wClip.GetClipboardData() # type: ignore
        wClip.CloseClipboard()
        return text

    def add_text(self, text):
        self.texts.append(text)
        self.texts_model.appendRow(QStandardItem(text))```



After searching online myself I guess that the problem may be due to the main event loop of Qt and the threading process of pynput.

I looked at the documentation of pynput and find out that the listener is actually a thread. But as I need to let the on_click function access the list of text the user have selected, I have to make the list global. Apart from the main question, I also wonder if there is a better approach for this.
````

Comment: If you don't use it on macOs, just use QClipboard and connect to the [`dataChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#dataChanged) signal.

Comment: Where does it hang? If it hangs at `listener.join()`, does it still hang if you comment out all Qt stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your attention, and now I have progressed in the problem. I have now find a solution that I think may not be appropriate, but it works. Also I think I just find it by luck and do not fully understand why this is different from the original question.

Here is the experience during finding it:

At first I tried to put the QT objects into one thread (not the main thread) and listeners into another thread. But this soon fails as I want to make communications between threads, since in the main event loop of Qt I cannot keep listening to a queue posted by the listeners. Also this will cause the warning of PyQt that I did not put the QApplication into the main thread, although I now have not understood the shortends of this approach.

Then here is my current solution, although I think it is not so elegant:

```
from copy_view import Copy_view
from drag import Drag
from key_control import get_select_text
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyboardListener
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.mouse import Button
import sys
import threading

global drag_copy_view

def listener():
    drag = Drag()

    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed and button == Button.left:
            drag.click(x, y)
        else:
            result = drag.release(x, y)
            if result:
                text = get_select_text()
                drag_copy_view.add_text(text)

    listener = MouseListener(on_click=on_click)
    listener.start()

    def on_press(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            listener.stop()
    exitListener = KeyboardListener(on_release=on_press)
    exitListener.start()

    listener.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    drag_copy_view = Copy_view() 
    drag_copy_view.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) # type: ignore
    drag_copy_view.show()

    listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=listener)
    listener_thread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just open another thread for the listeners, and the main thread is used for the Qt. This works now since basic features is implemented. But I still do not know whether this is a good practice.

This is because to update the content in the Qt I made a QWidget a global variable, and I now do not know whether this is common in using Qt or it is dangerous.